# API for Wikipedia in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, wikipedia-api

Does anybody know if there is an implementation of the Wikipedia API in Objective-C,
which can be used to access and display the information a bit nicer then with the plain website?
I'm thinking of something like the wikipanion app but not so sophisticated.

Answer (score 11):

I know the question is very old. But just for other ppl who are dealing with the same issue. I wrote a very small library which provides basic access to the Wikipedia API.

You can get it on github:
https://github.com/prine/WikiApiObjectiveC

Comment: I think this is a good and simple method. I am going to implement it.

Comment: How can I up-vote this answer? I down-voted it by accident yesterday and now it's locked. I just wanted to say thanks. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MediaWiki API to download the markup text](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Google%20App%20Engine&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content).

Also, why not look at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/ ?

Comment: hm yes I also considered the mobile version

Comment: but what I was looking for, was an framework which already parses the markup and splits it in parts

Comment: At this point, I should highlight that they give you the XML version so that you can parse the xml using DOM/SAX and get access to the data in a way which is much sleeker than a different API in every language, although I guess my next question would be, why re-invent the wheel?