# How to read the data from the wikipedia in iphone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [API for Wikipedia in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907817/api-for-wikipedia-in-objective-c)

I am implementing one iphone application in which I want to parse the data from the wikipedia document and dipply in my format.

I have seen one application on itunes its possible.

Please give me advice if its possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907817/api-for-wikipedia-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is running on MediaWiki engine. Check the [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API). Another way is to use[Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport) the And then you just parse the XML content. Also you should check the using guidelines page:[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F)